# Removing an event listener is removing for all items, despite the selector returning the correct item

Tags: jquery, event-handling, event-listener

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a[id^="MenuFilterVar_"]', onClickHandler);
jQuery(document).off('click', 'a[title="Special Case Element"]');
```

The above code attaches an event to the elements that meet the selector in `on()`. However, when I remove the event with `off()` in the subsequent line (a special case element within those original elements), it removes all of the events for the elements from line one.

To my understanding, `off()` should only remove the event from the items meeting the selector. Am I missing something in my understanding of `on/off`, or is there something wrong with my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you are binding the handler to the `document` and removing the handler that was bound to the `document`. So `.off` is removing all the handler since it is not direct binding..

Comment: @Vega Isn't jQuery(document) the context to use my binding? I thought that reads as: at the document level, bind this onclick handler to these elements. Admittedly, I'm pretty new to jQuery, so I could be wrong.

Comment: True.. They should be handling it.. but from your question it seems like they are not.. but let me double check.

Comment: From jQuery docs - _To remove specific delegated event handlers, provide a selector argument. The selector string must exactly match the one passed to .on() when the event handler was attached. To remove all delegated events from an element without removing non-delegated events, use the special value "**"._

Comment: @Vega so basically I can't do it that way with differing selectors.

Comment: @Vega You want to add that as an answer and I can accept it, then?

Comment: Sure.. but I am trying to make some workaround.. so that it is really useful.

Comment: See my answer below with a workaround to handle this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like for `.off` on delegated events you need to use the same selector as you have in `.on`. Below is from jQuery docs...

> To remove specific delegated event handlers, provide a selector argument. The selector string must exactly match the one passed to .on() when the event handler was attached. To remove all delegated events from an element without removing non-delegated events, use the special value "**".

http://api.jquery.com/off/

You can simply add that condition if it is just 1 element. See below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4rDgP/4/

```
function onClickHandler() {
    alert($(this).text());
}

jQuery(document).on('click', 'a[id^="MenuFilterVar_"]', function() {
    if (this.title == 'Special Case Element') return;   
    onClickHandler.call(this);
});
```

or If it is multiple elements then you can bind another handler for those elements you want to ignore and do an `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`. See below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4rDgP/3/

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a[title="Special Case Element"]', function (e) {
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}); 
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a[id^="MenuFilterVar_"]', onClickHandler);
```

Note that the `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` should be above the actual handler binding.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you change your selectors around, it should work.

```
jQuery('a[id^="MenuFilterVar_"]').on('click', onClickHandler);
jQuery('a[title="Special Case Element"]').off('click');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dboots/4rDgP/1/

Comment: yes, this is correct.  Per jquery  "When multiple filtering arguments are given, all of the arguments provided must match for the event handler to be removed."  By using the jQuery(document) for the "on", you have to use the exact same select for the "off".

Comment: @BenjaminPowers so how is this correct, then? Your comment differs from what his answer is showing.

Comment: Yes, it works (check the jsfiddle he included).  My comment is consistent with the answer in this way:  let's say that you have 3 elements that match the "MenuFilterVar_" selector.  If you use that selector in the .on(), you'll need to have those exact same 3 elements from a selector in the .off().  The answer works because putting the selector to the left of the .on() means that there will be 3 ons with a single element instead of 1 on for three elements.

Comment: @BenjaminPowers it doesn't work in my code, however. From jQuery: *To remove specific delegated event handlers, provide a selector argument. The selector string must exactly match the one passed to .on() when the event handler was attached. To remove all delegated events from an element without removing non-delegated events, use the special value "**".* 

I don't know why it works in jsfiddle, but it doesn't look like it's supposed to.